# I am creating an ios app using xcode without using the story board but i have a problem, i need to make my displays full screen but its not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Im currently creating an app using xcode (Swift) but most of my displays are not full screen and some are. 
my projects so far includes four viewer controllers:

login

sign up

forgot password

and home

When i launch the app you are able to sign in and taken to the home screen into your account (Which i managed to make full screen), however when the app is launched and a user is not signed in you are presented with the sign in page with two buttons:

"Dont have an account? Sign up" -> which takes you to the sign up form

"Forgot password" -> which takes you to the forgot password form

these two buttons do not work when the app is launched but when a user is signed into an account and logs out and taken back the to sign in form the two above button now work.
im not sure why this happens and not sure how to fix this can someone please help?

this is the code that allows you to switch to the different controllers:

from the sign in form to get to the sign up form

```
let signUpButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Don't have an account? Sign up", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 170/255, green: 170/255, blue: 170/255, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleShowSignUp), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func handleShowSignUp() {
      let signUpVC = SignUpVC()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signUpVC, animated: true)
  }
```

from the sign in form to get to the forgot password form:

```
let forgotPasswordButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Forgot password?", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 170/255, green: 170/255, blue: 170/255, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(forgotPassword), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func forgotPassword() {
    let forgotPassword = ForgotPasswordVC()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(forgotPassword, animated: true)

     }
```

Going back to my original question all the above is full screen until you log out from there everything goes back to the new card layout where you can see the previous view in the background and i have tried to add this line to all of the controllers but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
logInVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

(obviously formatted to the specific viewer controller)

how do i fix this?

i haven't added anything to my appdelegate file other than:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

i have added the following to my scene delegate:

```
       guard let mainScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
            window = UIWindow(windowScene: mainScene)
            let mainTabVC = MainTabVC()
            window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainTabVC)
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: show your appdelegate code

Comment: Can you show where are you presenting logInVC ??

Comment: @NabeelNazir what do you mean?  from when you log out.  this is the code that takes you back to the log in screen:           let logInVC = LogInVC()
                             let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: logInVC)
                            self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            logInVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

instead of

```
logInVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

Write this code before presenting navController.

I hope this will help you